# Django user_logged_in signal not fired when used with django-allauth "remember me"

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-allauth

I am using django-allauth framework to authenticate user logins. I have set up a signal that is fired every time the user logs in. I am also using the "remember me" option for user logins, so that the system remembers the user and does not ask for a username and password on subsequent logins after successful authentication.

What I am finding is that the signal fires when the user logs in with a username and password. However, when the user returns to the site and the login is authenticated with "Remember Me", i.e. she does not have to enter username and password; the signal is not fired.

I have tried this with both `django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_in` and `allauth.account.signals.user_logged_in` and the result is the same.

I am wondering how I can capture the user login when the user logs in with "Remember Me"?

Comment: As far as I understand enabling `ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER` keeps the session open as if the user has never logged out. It doesn't count as a new login.

Comment: @Selcuk thank you, I can see that now. Just tested by writing basic middleware that logs the session ID, and I can see that it's the same session ID every time I access the site, with "Remember Me" switched on. So I am wondering how else can I keep track of these user logins. All I ma trying to do is basically count every time the user uses the site.